# Why can't I take a link to a full size picture from the category?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get full-size pictures from product categories. This is the code I am using:

```
 $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $prod_cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
 $cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $cat_thumb_id, $size = 'large', $icon = false );
```

But I still get 150 x 150 pixel images back. ( shop_cat1-150x150.jpg ) What could be the matter, I am using correctly $size = 'large'. I have also tried:

```
 $cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $cat_thumb_id, 'large');
```

It still returns a link to a small image, even though the images themselves are large. Please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

At first, I need to change the *wp_get_attachment_thumb_url* to *wp_get_attachment_image_src* And here is the result:

```
$cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $cat_thumb_id, 'full');

<img src="<?php echo  $cat_thumb_url[0]; ?>" alt="img">
```

Perhaps there are other options, I will be glad to hear.